# Simple Registration Form. I would like to get rid of code duplications

Tags: android, kotlin

I don't like my current code, because of duplications. What's the best way to leverage Kotlin to make it more concise. I have simple registration form

```
data class RegisterForm @JvmOverloads constructor(
        val email: String = "",
        val emailError: String = "",

        val lastName: String = "",
        val lastNameError: String = "",

        ...
)
```

In my ViewModel I'm reacting to my `TextWatcher`. I set my state by updating my `RegisterForm` data class

```
fun onEmailChanged(email: String) {
    setState {
        copy(registerForm = registerForm
                .copy(email = email, emailError = validateEmail(email))
        ) }
}

fun onFirstNameChanged(text: String) {
    setState {
        copy(registerForm = registerForm
                .copy(firstName = text, firstNameError = validateFirstName(text))
        ) }
}
```

As you can see, I need to copy paste the code in my `ViewModel` every time I'm adding the new input field. How can I leverage `Kotlin` to get rid of these duplications?

Answer (score 2):

In functional programming terms, using [Lenses](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/basic-lensing) could help you modify nested object elegantly. There are no native supported lenses in kotlin language but some libraries provided. Check [klenses](https://github.com/poetix/klenses) or [arrow](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/optics/lens/).